# Python virtualenv installed package not found

Tags: python, django, package, virtualenv, pythonpath

I cannot import `django`in my fresh virtualenv installation (python 3.7.9).

So far :

- `$ virtualenv env`
- `$ source env\bin\activate`
- `$ (env) pip install django`
- `$ (env) pip freeze`

  `asgiref==3.3.1 Django==3.1.7 pytz==2021.1 sqlparse==0.4.1`

All good so far.
Except:

- `$ (env) python`
- `>>> import django`
  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`

I've tried :

- `where django-admin`
  `my_website/env/bin/django-admin`

So clealy if my command line can recognise it but not python, it has to do with PYTHONPATH.. I'm just not sure how to proceed now, it gets very confusing from here.

Note : I've also aliased my python version to 3.7.9 in bash.
`$ (env) python --version` `Python 3.7.9`

Comment: Are you using an IDE? I know sometimes you have to change the IDE interpreter settings to be able to import the module. If this is from the command line, then ignore this.

Comment: All from the command line unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Try running `which python`. It once happened to me where the command line said `(virtualenv)` but it was not running the Python in virtualenv/Scripts.

Comment: Good suggestion - python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3.7

Comment: So then my python is not running from my venv but from my default install ?

Comment: Could you show your `PATH`? After and before activate.

Comment: `$ echo $PATH` : `/Users/louisgrimaldi/Desktop/django-simple-ecommerce-master/env/bin:/Users/louisgrimaldi/.pyenv/shims:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/virtualenv:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands`

Comment: It is the same when activating venv.

Comment: One possibility - I've **aliased** my default python 3.9, which is too advanced for some packages, to python 3.7. `$ (env) which python`
`python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3.7`. Could it be that this alias overrides the virtualenv python, basically forcing it to use the default install ?

Comment: Definitely possible, one thing you can try is to use the full path to activate python. If that works, then the problem is your execution path. Mostly caused by your alias.

Comment: Did you use startproject to create?

Answer (score -1):

when activating the virtual environment, use following commands to install Django

```
# install django
python -m pip install django
# get pip freeze
python -m pip freeze
```